# Add ServiceStack.Interfaces with Nuget version 3.9.7.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, servicestack, nuget

I used Nuget to install ServiceStack.Text,ServiceStack.Client and ServiceStack.Common in version 3.9.7.0.

When trying to install ServiceStack.Interfaces version 3.9.7.0 it couldn`t find it.

If i still need the specific version of 3.9.7.0 what should i do?
I prefer to manage all my packages threw nuget..but if won`t have a choise i will use different solution.

Answer (score 2):

In ServiceStack `v3` the **ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll** was maintained in the [ServiceStack.Common](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/3.9.70) NuGet package, so to install a specific version of ServiceStack.Interfaces from NuGet you can specify the version you want:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Common -Version 3.9.70
```

See the [v3 installation docs](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) for other NuGet instructions.

Comment: Why was the version of ServicesStack.Interfaces was reset to 1.0.0.0?

Comment: @DevTraveler The version number became constant when [ServiceStack.Interfaces became Strong Named in v4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#servicestackinterfaces-is-now-strong-named)

Answer (score 1):

The ServiceStack.Interfaces library for ServiceStack v3 was reset to `1.0.0.0` when v4 was released, [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f1e56982bf5259f09f755289678674e31299d51d).

You can see the version information for the library here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs